# Why does LM2576 stop at 3.3Volts

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to step down 12 volts 3amps to work with a Raspberry Pi.  I'm using the [LM2576T-ADJ/NOPB](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=LM2576T-ADJ%2fNOPBvirtualkey59500000virtualkey926-LM2576T-ADJ%2fNOPB) along with the reference schematic/parts shown in the datasheet (100uf, 1000uf, 100uh, and a [diode](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=MBR360RLGvirtualkey58410000virtualkey863-MBR360RLG) )

When no load is connected, the voltage walks up to 12 volts; when I attached it to a 5v voltage regulator which is in turn hooked to the PI, it walks up to 3.3Volts and stops.

The question is, what part is limiting it to 3.3 volts?

Comment: Which particular LM2576 are you using ?  Such as : LM2576HVT-5.0 . There are many variations for this regulator.

Comment: For LM2756-ADJ, you can't use the schematic on p. 1 of the datasheet. See fig 22 on p. 11.

Comment: With the p. 1 schematic though, it should only give 1.23 V output. Can you show a photo of your construction?

Answer (score 1):

"The Photon" was correct, I was using the wrong Schematic for the variable version of the circuit.  Using the schematic on page 11 figure 22 and Adding the 2 resistors fixed the issue.